# Login con PHP, MySQL y ajax de jQuery no funciona correctamente

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

estuve revisando otros post muy parecidos al mío, probé código que han resuelto problemas, pero no logro hacer funcionar el mío.
El tema es simple :
Tengo un formulario de login con Boostrap 3 en mi archivo **login.php** :

```
          <div class="modal fade" id="modalLoginCliente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLoginCliente" style="font-family: Abel;">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ingreso de cliente</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"> 
                <!-- Acá van los controles de cambio de clave -->

                 <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Nombre de cliente :</label>  
                      <input type='text' id='txtUserName' name='txtUserName' class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de usuario del sistema">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Ingresar la clave :</label>            
                      <input type='password' id='txtUserPassword' name='txtUserPassword' class="form-control" placeholder="Clave de usuario">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label id='msg_login' style='color:blue;'></label>            
                  </div>

                <!-- Fin controles de cambio de calve -->

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" id="btn_salir_login" name="btn_salir_login" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                  <button type="button" id="login_user" name="login_user" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>            
        <!----------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Este es mi script que dispara la consulta y la recibe para habilitar el login según el valor recibido. **SCRIP**

```
<script>
$('#login_user').click(function(){

    if ( $('#txtUserName').val().length == 0 ) 
    {
       alert('Debe ingresar su nombre de usuario');
       $('#txtUserName').focus();
       $('#txtUserName').select();
    }  
    else if ( $('#txtUserPassword').val().length == 0 ) 
    {
       alert('Debe ingresar la clave de acceso');
       $('#btn_salir_login').focus();
       $('#btn_salir_login').select();
    } 
    else  
    {
      $.ajax(
      {
        type: 'POST',
        url:'login_user.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{'username': $('#txtUserName').val() , 'pass': $('#txtUserPassword').val()},
        success: function(data)
        {   
           if(data)
           {
             console.log(data);
             $('#msg_login').html('Acceso al sistema ok');
             $('#msg_login').css("color", "green")
           } 
        },
        error:function(data)
        {
           $('#msg_login').html('Error en acceso al sistema');
           $('#msg_login').css("color", "red"); 
           $('#txtUserName').focus();
           $('#txtUserName').select() 
        }        
      });
    }      
});
</script>
```

Y este es mi código PHP que hace la consulta a la base de datos y devuelve un array (en realidad el array lo devuelve por si más adelante necesito usar esos datos, por ahora no lo veo necesario ya que carga los mismos datos que carga en variables SESSION) **PHP**

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  ob_start();
  include('set_db.php');
  include('funciones.php');

   $mysql_server = $MYSQL_HOST ; 
   $mysql_username = $MYSQL_LOGIN ;
   $mysql_password = $MYSQL_PASS ;
   $mysql_database = $MYSQL_DB ;
   $mysql_table = 'clientes';
   $crypt_pass = encriptar($_GET['pass']);

   session_start(); // este por si no la has iniciado en la pagina que planeas destruirla, de lo contrario no te destruirá nada
   session_destroy();
   session_unset();  

   $username=$_POST['username'];
   $pass=$_POST['pass'];

   $db = mysqli_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

   if (!$db)
   {
      die('Error al conectarse al servidor<br>'.mysqli_error($db));
   }

   mysqli_select_db($db, $mysql_database) or die('Error al conectarse a la base de datos<br>'.mysqli_error($db));
   mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8');
   mysql_set_charset('utf8', $db);
   $db->set_charset("utf8");
   mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$mysql_table." WHERE username = '".$username."' AND clave_acceso='".$crypt_pass."'";
   $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

   if ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {     
       session_start();

       $_SESSION['id_cliente'] = $data['id_cliente'];
       $_SESSION['username'] = $data['username'];
       $_SESSION['fullname'] = $data['nombres'].' '.$data['apellidos']; 
       $_SESSION['expires_by'] = time() + $session_timeout;
       $_SESSION['expires_timeout'] = $session_timeout;                                               

       $data_user=array("id_cliente"=>$data['id_cliente'],"username"=>$data['username'],"fullname"=>$data['nombres'].' '.$data['apellidos'] );

       $username = isset($_COOKIE['username']) ? $_COOKIE['username'] : '';
       $password = isset($_COOKIE['password']) ? $_COOKIE['password'] : '';

       echo json_encode(array('id_cliente' => $data['id_cliente'], 'username' => $data['username']));

   } 

   mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

Ya probé de varias formas la consulta, si la ejecuto aparte me muestra los datos que necesito, pero al ejecutar el login, SIEMPRE va a parar a la función de error del $.Ajax, nunca me lleva al **success: function(data)**
Revisé la consulta y funciona perfecto, revisé el formato json y está bien, probé con GET y POST y lo mismo.
Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: Revisa la consola del navegador, si te lleva a **error** en lugar de **success** es porque se produjo un fallo al enviar la petición, probablemente la ruta de **login_user.php** es incorrecta. Adicionalmente, en **error** agrega `console.log(data);` para ver la respuesta que estás recibiendo.

Comment: Hola Triby, gracias por la respuesta, la ruta del archivo login_user.php es la misma del login.php, le agregué el   consoledata.log(data)  y no me muestra nada en la consola...sigo luchando.Gracias nuevamente y saludos.

Comment: Para tratar de identificar el error, revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792878/jquery-ajax-error-function#answer-14563181

Comment: @WalterMesón prueba remover ob_start y pon session_start() al principio de tu pagina, por otro lado json_encode no devuelve nada muchas veces si la respuesta contiene caracteres extraños, podrias mostrar la consola y la respuestaq que te da, tambien verificar en el network si no tienes un 404, adicionalmente posees dos `session_start()`

Comment: Muchas gracias @stan chacon, me sirvió tu ejemplo.Saludos

Comment: @WalterMesón Espero puedas votarla si te ha sido de utilidad

Answer (score 0):

Aquí adjunto un ejemplo de como realizo un login simple en un directorio de contacto que utilizo en la empresa que trabajo:

```
session_start();
require_once 'db.php';
if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['ultima_actividad']) && (time() - $_SESSION['ultima_actividad'] > 1800)) {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    }else {
        $_SESSION['ultima_actividad'] = time();
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['accion'])) {
    $accion = $_POST['accion'];
    $db = new DB();
    $conn = $db->getInstancia();
    switch ($accion) {
        case 'getDirectorio':
         //algun codigo
        break;
     case 'getLogin':
    try {
        $usuario = isset($_POST['usuario']) ? $_POST['usuario'] : '';
        $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
        if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $usuario) && preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+((\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?|(\@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?)$/",$password)) {
            $sql =  "SELECT count(*) conteo FROM `usuario` WHERE usuario = UPPER(?) and clave = ?";   //prepared statements
            $query = $conn-> prepare($sql);
            $query -> execute(array($usuario,$password));   //prepared statements value
            $query -> setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // [PDO::FETCH_NUM for integer key value]
            $result = $query -> fetch();
            if ($result["conteo"] > 0) {
                $_SESSION["usuario"] = strtoupper($usuario);
                $_SESSION['ultima_actividad'] = time();
                echo json_encode($result);
            }else {
                echo json_encode(array('conteo'=>0));
            }
        }else {
            echo json_encode(array('conteo'=>-1));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "error";
    }
    break;
    case 'checkSession':
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'none'));
    }else {
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'ok'));
    }
    break;
    case 'logout':
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'none'));
    }else {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['usuario']);
        unset($_SESSION['ultima_actividad']);
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'ok'));
    }
    break;
  }
}//end isset
```

espero te sea de utilidad